# Java:adding char to a specific position in a Strings(Performance)

Tags: java, string, algorithm, arraylist

I'm looking for the efficient way to add a char to a specific position in a String.

My example:

```
package test;

public class Test {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

      //Creating A String Object that Hold "Hello"  
      String  seq = new String("Hello");
      System.out.println(seq);/*printing Hello*/

      /*putting tha char _ in the 3 Position :  He_llo */
      seq = seq.substring(0, 2)+ "_" + seq.substring(2, seq.length());
      System.out.println(seq);/*it prints He_llo*/

  }
```

It's only a simple function , but in my real program I am dealing with:

- 1- Strings that are 400-600 character Long.
- 2- I will make a lot of call to add the _ char in the middle of The
  Strings.

Using String Object or StringBuilder Object are not the best Object to use in my opinion , because this operation `seq = seq.substring(0, 2)+ "_" + seq.substring(2, seq.length());`
 take  O(n) in the Worst Case.

My question:

What is the Collection Appropriate for this Purpose?

I think using a list Of character Object, so it will take Only O(1) for insertion , but i'm not sure.

Could you give me some insight Please.

Thank you.

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder`. Also this: "I think using A list Of character Object , so it will took Only O(1) for insertion" is wrong.

Comment: Could you please answer why it will not take Only O(1).Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [StringBuilder.insert](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert(int,%20java.lang.String))?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410009/1398418

Comment: Insertion will be O(1), but that's going to be a gigantic **1** when all the allocations are factored in. Getting to the insertion point will get O(n), too, so there is going to be no way to earn a free lunch just for using a better data structure. If the current way is too slow, which you should measure, you will need to factor in your algorithm to make a decision.

Comment: The complexity of concatenating two strings is linearly dependent on the length of the constituent strings, as their contents are copied to a new location.  Thus, `O(n)`.

Comment: Depending on how exactly you're inserting, it may be worthwhile to use a linked list.

Comment: My Opinion was Choosing an Unsorted linked list normally it took  O(1) to insert a char to a specific position , i don't understand why you are saying that it's the same thing as using String or StringBuilder.Thanks for every One that tried to answer My Question.

Comment: Linked list has O(1) insertion time, but O(n) iteration time to get to the insertion point. So it depends if you're inserting iteratively or if you need random access.

Comment: i know already the position where i should add the char .something like MyList.add(2,'_') will not itirate !!

Comment: Yes, it will have to iterate if you're using a linked list.

Comment: `MyList.add(2,'_')` will either iterate to find position 2 (if `LinkedList`), or iterate to move all elements after position 2 (if `ArrayList`). In either case, iteration is involved.

Comment: Thanks For everyOne , but there is a  difference  between the String , Stringbuilder and The Lists . in the List we will not copy the other Character after the Insertion may be we have to iterate but after the insertion we have no more work.and it's worse in The StringBuilder I think because we have a postWork to do.

Comment: @zakzak What "postWork" do you have to do with `StringBuilder` that you don't have to do with `List<Character>`? And you seem to be ignoring the cost of boxing all the characters to even build a list in the first place.

Comment: copied from another discution. postWork : an insert (StringBuilder)may involve up to 3 System.arraycopy (native) calls .with list we have no copy to done.

Comment: @zakzak I see only 2, one of them is rare only when you will be at max capacity and you can make sure it won't happen if you create it with the correct capacity. One more important thing that you're missing is because of how modern computers work ArrayList is much faster then LinkedList(arrayCopy is a very fast operation compared to iterating over a linked list).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case I would use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) :)

```
String yourString = "Hello";
    
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(yourString);
sb.insert(2, '_');
    
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

The output is: He_llo

*EDIT: Replaced StringBuffer with StringBuilder*

Comment: Since question is about performance, why use the synchronized `StringBuffer` class, and not the newer (Java 5+) `StringBuilder` class? The javadoc you linked when says it: *As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, `StringBuilder`. The `StringBuilder` class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization.*

Comment: More generally, why would you ever use a `StringBuffer` (other than for [`Matcher.appendReplacement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-))?

Comment: @shmosel And even that is no longer needed in Java 9: [`Matcher.appendReplacement​(StringBuilder sb, String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuilder-java.lang.String-)

Comment: @Andreas And even that is (almost) no longer needed in Java 9: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: @Likas Bauer Friendly question did you test run the code or did you proof read it? Here is the fix StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(yourString); From one newbies to another